# JRE 7 SSL Exception UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: ssl, sslexception

I have an applet that attempts to fetch content from a specific HTTPS URL. 
I used the following sample code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlLink);

URLConnection urlConn = (URLConnection)url.openConnection(); //https:link
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
urlConn.setUseCaches(false);

urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en");
urlConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-length",String.valueOf(data.length()));
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(data);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

I intermittently receive the following exception:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
AWT-EventQueue-2, handling exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
%% Invalidated:  [Session-6, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
AWT-EventQueue-2, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
AWT-EventQueue-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 50                               ......P
AWT-EventQueue-2, called closeSocket()
AWT-EventQueue-2, called close()
AWT-EventQueue-2, called closeInternal(true)

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
.....
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineWrap(CipherSpi.java:870)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.wrap(Cipher.java:2417)
        at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        ... 33 more
```

On checking the CipherSpi.engineWrap implementation, I see the following:

```
protected byte[]  engineWrap(Key key)
        throws IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException

    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

Kindly advice....

Comment: I'm experiencing the very same problem. @user2599784, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not set `Content-length`. `HttpURConnection` will do that for you automatically.